# Spring Boot + Liquibase: partial rollout and columnDefinition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I'm migrating to a different database. Previously there was a different mechanism to use schema migrations, but for the new database I'll be using Liquibase. As a way to make the rollout safer I'd like to first rollout just the schema migrations for the new database. I'll be using Liquibase specific data source config (spring.liquibase.url, ...)

The new database uses a different type for one of the columns, ie previously a type was UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, now it'll be UUID.

Is there a way to have a @Column( ... , columnDefinition = "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER") only applied for a regular datasource, but not liquibase data source?

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much Liquibase related question, you basically have 2 slightly different database schemas that you want to support.

`@Column`, and `@Entity` are JPA directives and cannot be conditionally aware of the Spring configuration context. But if you have your different data sources configured to load based on the Spring profile, you could have different Entity implementations for the DB tables that are different, and load those based on the profile as well.

You could have one package for common entities, one package for the datasource 1 and second package for datasource 2. And then based on the active profile load:

- base package + package 1

```java
@Profile("old")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.app.model.common", "com.app.model.old"})
@Configuration
public class OldDatasourceConfig
```

- base package + package 2

```java
@Profile("new")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.app.model.common", "com.app.model.new"})
@Configuration
public class NewDatasourceConfig
```

Comment: I think the Spring profile is the same in both cases here. Liquibase applies the migrations on startup, but the profile is the same. I hope there is a way to distinguish the cases based on whether it's Liquibase data source or main Spring Boot data source ...

Comment: I'm also not specifying the DataSource configuration in code explicitly, just using the appropriate spring.liquibase properties.